# Calculus of variations

Tags: calculus-of-variations

The particular function that extremises a certain functional $J$ among all the functions that render $L$ to another functional $K$ also gives an extremum to the functional $K$ among all the functions that give $J$ a presribed value.

How would I go about proving or disproving this: a proof using the Euler-Lagrange equation?